# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

My function doesn't take any arguments but I get this error `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`. I can print the values on the terminal but can't be displayed on the browser.

I am fetching data from two database tables(Postgres) and put it in a select input in Django template.

This is the method suppose to return the data to be displayed

```
def get_categories():
    myvars = {}
    sdet = {}
    items = CategoriesDB.objects.all()
    vals = '<option value="">Please Select Category</option>'

    try:
        for item in items:
            section_id = item.section_id
            gname = repr(item.section.section_name)
            sdet[section_id] = gname
            category_id = item.id
            category_name = item.category_name
            gcat = {'id': category_id, 'name': category_name}
            if section_id not in myvars:
                myvars[section_id] = [gcat]
            else:
                myvars[section_id].append(gcat)
        for var in myvars:
            otitle = sdet[var]
            otl = len(otitle)
            tshort = '%s ...' % (otitle[:100]) if otl > 100 else otitle
            vals += '<optgroup label="%s" title="%s">' % (tshort, otitle)
            gitems = myvars[var]
            for i, itm in enumerate(gitems):
                gname = str(itm['name'])
                itm_id = itm['id']
                itl = len(gname)
                itms = '%s ...' % (gname[:100]) if itl > 100 else gname
                vals += '<option value="%s" title="%s">%s</option>' % (
                    itm_id, gname, itms)
            vals += '</optgroup>'
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    else:
        # on returning vals - I get the error not enough to unpack
        return vals
```

This is the forms file

```
categories = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=get_categories(),
        initial='0',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control selectpicker',
                   'data-size': '10',
                   'data-live-search': 'true',
                   'data-style': 'btn-white',
                   'data-parsley-errors-container': '#gc_error',
                   'id': 'goods_category'}))
```

This is the html file

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Category of Goods <span class="asteriskField">* 
       </span></label>
         {{ form.categories }}
       <span id="gc_error"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/forms/cargo/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mins_auth',
 'mins_forms',
 'mins_main',
 'mins_payment',
 'mins_reports',
 'mins_bonds',
 'mins_docs',
 'mins_search',
 'captcha')
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
   4 : <!--[if !IE]><!-->
   5 : <html lang="en">
   6 : <!--<![endif]-->
   7 : <head>
   8 :   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   9 :   <title>Marine Insurance | {% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   10 :   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\mins_forms\views.py", line 286, in cargo
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\mins_forms\views.py", line 284, in cargo
    'premium_limit': premium_limit})
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 971, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 33, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 89, in as_widget
    attrs = self.build_widget_attrs(attrs, widget)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 224, in build_widget_attrs
    if widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial) and self.field.required and self.form.use_required_attribute:
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 700, in use_required_attribute
    return use_required_attribute and first_choice is not None and self._choice_has_empty_value(first_choice)
  File "C:\Users\NKorir\Desktop\Backup\WorksWell\insurity\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 686, in _choice_has_empty_value
    value, _ = choice

Exception Type: ValueError at /forms/cargo/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

I've tried multiple stackoverflow solutions but no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your html file

Comment: I've updated @kyore

Comment: Why don't you just use `ModelChoiceField`?

Comment: django forms provides `forms.choiceField` gives the normal form functionality.

Comment: It appears your function get_categories() returns a string and you are trying to assign it to choices which expects another data type, a tuple I guess.

Comment: @Trevor that's actually where the problem. Thanks for identifying that. Could you maybe share how I can change the data output to a tuple, maybe some few codes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make get_categories() return a tuple/list of tuples. To return a list of tuples you can use something like:

```
vals = [("", "Please Select Category")]
vals.append(("id1", "Value1"))
vals.append(("id2", "Value2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

GItems seems to be a variable that's not a map or list, seeing it's initialized from myvars(car). Your for loop expects to unpack both index and value.

So the gitems variable is not iterable